# Reproducible PyTorch Model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I'm using PyTorch (1.7.1), PyTorch Geometric (1.6.3), NVIDIA Cuda (11.2).

I need to make a reproducible neural networks for a competition.

However, when I try with:

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
rand = 123
torch.manual_seed(rand)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(rand)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(rand)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
np.random.seed(rand)
random.seed(rand)
```

, the results and loss appeared differently each time. How can I fix it?

(For reference, it always comes out the same in `device = torch.device('cpu')`.)

I'm using jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting torch to throw an error if you're calling something that isn't deterministic.

```
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)
```